# Dynotopo or shift+r, what´s the difference?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

So I am watching a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usbupwLRENE) and I see shift+r (used in sculptmode) for the first time. But I don´t quite understand it.
In the tutorial it looks like the grid appears to enable adding more topology.[image: Shift+r]

It seems to me, that it works more or less like dynotopology, so what´s the difference? The weird thing is, that in the video the grab tool is used to add detail. When I do it nothing happens. Than again the term remesh seems to matter, but I thought it means to create a lowpoly mesh on top of a highpoly one. That´s a step that doesn´t happen up to that point.

Answer (score 0):

*Dyntopo* is generally used to add details on the part you'll paint. To be able to add details it will subdivide this part and triangulate the faces. The size of the faces will depend on the *Detail Size* value. It also can be used to simplify if you choose a high enough *Detail Size* value.

*Remesh* is generally used to simplify the topology but you can also use it to make it denser. It will affect the whole topology and it will create quads. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to choose the size of the quads, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to apply.

The *Grab* brush won't add details, it will just deform the current topology.

Comment: Ok, but can you tell me how to confirm a number from the shift+r grid, just like in the video? I can´t figure out what he does. I just want the mesh to look as smooth.

Comment: once you've chosen the size of the quads with Shift R, validate with Ctrl R